# html text field

Tags: html, css

which property is used for write all text for capitalize in textfield. 
And how?
please reply

Comment: `text-transform: capitalize;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css property "text-transform":

```
.myClassName {text-transform:capitalize;}
```

[link for details](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There's no attribute that says "this field can only contain capital letters".  What you might be able to do is add `text-transform: uppercase` to the CSS for the text box, but the actual value of the box will still contain mixed case.

If that's not good enough, you could add an `onchange` event handler that says something like `this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();`.  That'd alter the value passed back to the server, or the value your scripts see (as opposed to the CSS, which only alters the value the *user* sees).